# is there a tried-and-true pattern for explaining required oauth permissions?

Tags: web

I'm building a webapp that depends on oauth with an outside provider. Before I send the user to the oauth page I'd like to explain to them why I need the permissions I do. Obviously I cannot do this on the oauth page since it's owned by a 3rd party. So I'd like to explain somehow *before* the user is redirected to the oauth page.

A couple ideas I had were:

- popup a new window before redirecting that shows an image of what they should expect and explains everything. this could be annoying (ugh popups) and won't work well on mobile
- requiring 2 clicks - the first "login" button wouldn't actually redirect to the oauth page but rather shows some sort of instructions and contain another login button that actually does the redirect. this is also kind of annoying though since it's an extra step.

Can someone point me to a site that does this well already?

Answer (score 1):

You could either describe it in a nutshell on the page where the oauth click happens  or you could use link to a new page where it's described in detail. I would advice *against* a mandatory popup window as you can't be sure that all users are interested in the description (as a lot of users might already know the pros and cons of oauth) - and popups in general are quite annoying. Giving the fact that most oauth provider rely on popups, that would be two popups in a row.

This is an example (and [here's the live version](http://www.setlist.fm/signin)):

[image: Help link before click]